# Should I explain the consequences of the contributions in the contribution section?

Tags: academic-writing, research

Should I explain the consequences of the contributions in the contribution section of a research paper?

For instance, what is the best option between these two (if any)?

> In this paper, we provide the following contribution:
>
> - We prove that if X is a complete metric space and T: X -> X is a contraction mapping then there is a unique fixed point.

or

> In this paper, we provide the following contribution:
>
> - We prove that if X is a complete metric space and T: X -> X is a contraction mapping then there is a unique fixed point. **The consequences of this theorem are ...**

Comment: I think you are missing an "IF" in both formulations; "... and **if** T:X->X is a contraction mapping..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not provide the consequences; those are detailed in the paper itself.

If anything, you have an abstract at the front of the paper that will tend toward that, e.g.

> We will show that there is a unique fixed point in this transformed mapping, thus demonstrating the viability of Finkleworth's proposal. We then implement that and demonstrate ...